# Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "password"

Tags: forms, symfony, variables, error-handling

I created a form to allow user to register. Then, I used the same form to allow user to edit his informations. I created his profile page on login.html.twig and I wish to allow him to access to one button so that when he clicks on it, I can upload his picture, and without clicking on submit button his picture would be sent to data.

The file isn't stored and its name is not sent to my database, and it ended up with this error **Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "password"** which I don't understand because the form is also display on the page where user can edit all other informations, and there is no problem to keep password inputs empty.

How can make it work ?

I'll be so grateful if you help me find the solution.

login.html.twig

```
{% block body %}

{% if app.user %}

{{ form_start(form, {'attr' : {'class' : 'position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle'}} )  }}
    {{ form_widget(form.photo, {'attr' : {'onChange' : 'this.form.submit();'}} ) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.gender, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.lastname, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.firstname, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.birthdate, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.occupation, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.nationality, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.nativelanguage, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.first, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.second, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr' : {'class' : 'd-none'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_user_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', [
            'users' => $userRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/register', name: 'register', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function createUser(
        Request $request,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface,
        UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasherInterface
    ){
        $user = new User();
        $userform = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $userform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userform->isSubmitted() && $userform->isValid()) {
            $user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);

            $plainPassword = $userform->get('password')->getData();
            $hashedPassword = $userPasswordHasherInterface->hashPassword($user, $plainPassword);
            $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($user);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->render('front/register.html.twig', [
            'userform' => $userform->createView()
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/user/{id}', name: 'app_user_show', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show(User $user): Response
    {
        return $this->render('user/show.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
    
    #[Route('/profile', name: 'profile')]
    public function addPhoto(
        Request $request,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        SluggerInterface $sluggerInterface,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface
    ){
        $connected = $this->getUser();
        $useremail = $connected->getUserIdentifier();
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $useremail]);

        $userform = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $userform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userform->isSubmitted() && $userform->isValid()) {
            $imagefile = $userform->get('photo')->getData();

            if ($imagefile){
                $originalFileName = pathinfo($imagefile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $safeFileName = $sluggerInterface->slug($originalFileName);
                $newFileName = $safeFileName . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $imagefile->guessExtension();
    
                $imagefile->move(
                    $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
                    $newFileName
                );
    
                $user->setPhoto($newFileName);
            }

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($user);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }

        return $this->renderForm('security/login.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $userform,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/update', name: 'update')]
    public function updateUser(
        Request $request,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface,
        UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasherInterface
    ){
        $connected = $this->getUser();
        $useremail = $connected->getUserIdentifier();
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $useremail]);

        $userform = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $userform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userform->isSubmitted() && $userform->isValid()) {

            $plainPassword = $userform->get('password')->getData();
            $hashedPassword = $userPasswordHasherInterface->hashPassword($user, $plainPassword);
            $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($user);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->renderForm('front/edituser.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $userform,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/delete', name: 'delete')]
    public function deleteUser(
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface
    ){
        $connected = $this->getUser();
        $useremail = $connected->getUserIdentifier();
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $useremail]);
        
        $entityManagerInterface->remove($user);
        $entityManagerInterface->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }
}
```

UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\LanguageType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Je suis ...' => '',
                    'un homme' => 'male',
                    'une femme' =>'female',
                    'non-binaire' => 'non-binary'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdate', BirthdayType::class, [
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Année', 'month' => 'Mois', 'day' => 'Jour',
                ],
                'choice_translation_domain' => true
            ])
            ->add('occupation')
            ->add('nationality', CountryType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis un pays',
            ])
            ->add('nativelanguage', LanguageType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis ta langue maternelle',
            ])
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'empty_data' => ''
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Les deux mots de passe doivent être identiques.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
                'empty_data' => ''
            ])
            ->add('photo', FileType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thing about it.  The user does not want to change the password so they leave it blank.  The form gets posted with a blank password so you code tries to hash the blank password and bad things happen.  You can't send the original password as default because it is hashed so you can't ever get it.  You might take a look at [Symfony Validation Groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) which basically allows you to use one form in different settings.  But for myself, I just create a different form for these sorts of things.

Comment: Thank you very much Cerad. I took a look at the link that I sent. I believe this is a good lead. I am trying to follow what it's said but I don't know how to use the code. Could you help me ?

Comment: Or how would you do it ? You said you would just create a different form ?

Comment: I personally just make an individual form for each use case.  But quite a few people use validation groups.  I'd suggest working through the example in the docs and then decide which fits best for you.  I confess I am a bit confused by your posted code becase the /profile route maps to addPhoto which in turn uses the login template?

Comment: You are right, I wanted to change this last point. Thank you for your help Cerad. I am going to dig all of these a little bit.

Comment: Dividing my UserType.php in two files was the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many years of using symfony - I would also (as @Cerad already did) suggest you to create multiple form-classes for different scenarios. There's nothing wrong to have dozens `*Type.php` in your `src/Form` directory.

- Create an `UserRegisterationType` for registration **only**.
- Create an `UserDataEditType` to update user's data (e.g. from some kind of
  `/admin` where all fields are editable. Or maybe some additional fields, like a checkbox to resend an activation email to this user.)
- Create an `UserProfileEditType` to let user update **only some data** if it's profile.

I think you get the Idea.

###### About user's profile page. (I know it's kinda off - but just to prove my point)

My personal rule of thumb - to create many "small" forms for such "special cases" like "change password" or/and "change email" or/and "delete account/profile". With such approach, you can react to specific action more precise. It's not convenient (and more error-prone) to have one big form, where user could change password **and** change email and click at **only one submit** button so save it all.

in `UserProfileController.php`

```php
/**
 * PSEUDO_CODE. UNTESTED.
 *
 *
 * @param Request $reuqest
 * @return Response
 */
public function editProfile(Request $reuqest): Response
{
    // some mandatory stuff for user-profile page...
    
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');


    $changePwdForm = $this->createForm(UserProfileChangePasswordType::class, $user);
    $changeEmailForm = $this->createForm(UserProfileChangeEmailType::class, $user);
    $deleteAccountForm = $this->createForm(UserProfileDeleteAccountType::class, $user);


    if ($reuqest->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
        $changePwdForm->handleRequest($reuqest);

        if ($changePwdForm->isSubmitted() && $changePwdForm->isValid()) {
            // apply your user-changed-pwd logic, save, add flash-message and redirect (e.g. to profile-edit page)
            // maybe you want to force user to re-login with new pwd after this... or log out user on all _other_ devices...
        }

        $changeEmailForm->handleRequest($reuqest);

        if ($changeEmailForm->isSubmitted() && $changeEmailForm->isValid()) {
            // same here.. apply your logic, save, maybe send confirmation-email to new address and so on...
            // redirect.
        }

        $deleteAccountForm->handleRequest($reuqest);

        if ($deleteAccountForm->isSubmitted() && $deleteAccountForm->isValid()) {
            // double-check if user sure about this and, maybe, perform some additional checks...
            // save, logout and redirect to homepage..
        }

    }

    return $this->render('user_profile/edit_profile.html.twig', [
        'changePasswordForm' => $changePwdForm->createView(),
        'changeEmailForm'    => $changeEmailForm->createView(),
        'deleteAccountForm'  => $deleteAccountForm->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

somewhere in your `user_profile/edit_profile.html.twig` template

```
{% if changePasswordForm is defined and changePasswordForm|default %}
    {{ form_start(changePasswordForm) }}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Change Password ...
        </legend>

        {{ form_rest(changePasswordForm) }}
    </fieldset>
    {{ form_end(changePasswordForm) }}
{% endif %}


{% if changeEmailForm is defined and changeEmailForm|default %}
    {{ form_start(changeEmailForm) }}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Change E-mail ...
        </legend>

        {{ form_rest(changeEmailForm) }}
    </fieldset>
    {{ form_end(changeEmailForm) }}
{% endif %}


{% if deleteAccountForm is defined and deleteAccountForm|default %}
    {{ form_start(deleteAccountForm) }}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Delete your account ...
        </legend>
        {{ form_rest(deleteAccountForm) }}
    </fieldset>
    {{ form_end(deleteAccountForm) }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {{form_end(form)}}, I used {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}, as explained in the [Symfony Twig documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables).

It worked well. :)